# Laravel paginate, changing the query string to search

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-5, pagination

Currently trying to paginate some results on a product object.

The paginate object that I am receiving in my view `{{ $products->links() }}` is returning correctly however instead of the query being "test.com/search?search=test&page2" it is returning "test.com/search?query=test&page2" how can i change it so it returns search instead of query?

The html output is:

```
<a href="http://test.dev/search?query=test&amp;page=2">2</a>
```

but what i need is:

```
<a href="http://test.dev/search?search=test&amp;page=2">2</a>
```

EDIT:
Controller:

```
public function searchable(Request $request)
{

    // search database, with result, list on page, with links to products,
    $products = Product::search($request->search)->paginate(3);

    return view('search.index', compact('products', 'request'));
}


use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Product extends Model
{
use Searchable;

/**
 * Creates searchable index for product model
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
public function searchableAs()
{
    return 'products_index';
}
}
```

form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/search', 'method' => 'GET', 'files' => 'false')) }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="submit" class="custom-search-button btn btn-lrg btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="search-bar" type="search" name="search" placeholder="type keyword(s) here" />
        </div>
    </div>
    {{-- <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/> --}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have field named `query` in your search form. Change its name to `search`, adjust logic in controller to be using `search` param instead of `query` and you are done.

Comment: {{ Form::open(array('url' => '/search', 'method' => 'GET', 'files' => 'false')) }}
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <button type="submit" class="custom-search-button btn btn-lrg btn-primary">Search</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-10">
       <input class="search-bar" type="search" name="search" placeholder="type keyword(s) here" />
      </div>
     </div>
 {{ Form::close() }}

Comment: post your controller logic, and middleware if you custmized it. That is really weird

Comment: updated the question. Any ideas? Or should I use the query as the search string because the defulat in the paginate calls query["query" => "test"]

Comment: If you dont really need `search` in your `$_GET`, change it to `query`

Comment: search is the route so hits test.com/search so changing to query would make no difference to the web route

Comment: Change input name to query ... No more replies.